# SP2013: Creating a Loop in a Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am attempting to create a workflow that has a loop. The idea is to have the loop check for date and time and returns the date/time to the list library that the workflow is connected to. As well sending an email.  These are the steps that I have taken so far

1. In SPD select List and Libraries
2. Select List Workflows (title...etc.)
3. Select Loop w/conditions (This would be the action)
4. Create Initiation Parameters
5. Create another Action for sending an email

I am not sure if I have the steps correct.  Not producing the correct outcome, therefore, there must be steps that I am missing.  Has anyone successfully accomplished this type of workflow for date/time?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you want a loop? Or do you just want it to pull a set date? If I'm reading that correctly, it sounds like you just want it to check a date and time, and fill in a date/time field with that information. Running a loop would just have it constantly trying to loop until the date met a certain time. Would a "Pause until conditions are met be a better fit?

Comment: Hi @JoshMcClain No, I am not 100% sure that I need a loop, but I thought that may be the best option. Sorry I wasn't clear in my question.  I have a list of items with a start date connect to each item.  A wanted a workflow that would loop each day through the list. If a start date is greater than or equal to today's date I want a email notification to be sent.  Would a loop still fit in this case?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure no worries. Yeah if you haven't tried the "Pause until" function in the Workflows, try that out to see if it fits your needs. You can essentially tell it to wait until a certain date, be it a calculated one or one set via a SP field, and the workflow will just hang out and wait until that time, and then run. If you need it to run again, unfortunately, that takes more work. As it will only fire once.

Comment: @JoshMcClain Thanks for your help. I have a better understanding. I will try "wait for..." action. Thanks, again.